# Flip Animation - Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, visibility, css-animations, css-transforms

I have been using a script I found online for a flip animation in an application I am building. The flip works on all browsers except for IE. Can anyone send me a fix that will help sort this out please. An example can be seen here at: http://jsfiddle.net/jamcrowe/As5vT/

```
- .flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
    -ms-perspective: 800;
   height: 340px;
   position: relative;
    background: red;
    width: 200px
}
- .flip .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
```

Comment: IE10 the issue is with

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the jquery version, there are some issues for IE Jquery 10.x. 
I hope it helps

Comment: I think it is an issue with the backface-visibility. Im basing that on research that i've done today of course